# Does LynxOS supports QT and QML? If Yes then which version

Tags: qt, qml, lynxos

Need to know if LynxOS supports QT and QML. If yes then which version of QT

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, it should be the opposite: Do Qt and QML have support for LynxOS? And for that you first of all should go to the Qt homepages and look.

Comment: The best way to find out is to try to compile Qt for that OS. As long as it is POSIX-conform (which according to wikipedia it is), it should work. You might have to create a custom mkspec and find the correct configure parameters, but it should be possible

Comment: The official Qt documentation ([http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html) shows that Qt is available for a list of operating systems. LynxOS is not included, however, the qt5 repository contains makespec for LynxOS and seems to be active (https://github.com/qt/qtbase). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a recent C++11 compiler and will have to compile from source for sure.  Also you will need a number of open source projects that Qt depends on, but should be do able.